# WP_Query and acf date field does not sort right

Tags: php, wordpress, filtering, advanced-custom-fields, meta-query

I am trying to only see posts after or equal to today and sort ASC, my date field outputs Ymd, the first part (only see posts after or equal to today) works but the sorting does not.

```
$today = date ('Ymd');
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'diensten', 
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,   
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'datum_dienst',
            'value' => $today,
            'compare' => '>='
        )
    ),
    'meta_key'  => 'datum_dienst',
    'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'     => 'ASC',
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: what if you 'orderby' => 'meta_value' ?

Comment: @Tami That also does not work, thank you for the comment tho!

Comment: Bummer. That should have worked, I am sure I have done this in the past successfully this way, so your problem could be somewhere else.
If you want my help, could you share more details about what exactly does not work? I would also need to see what $loop = new WP_Query( $args ); returns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the few people facing the same problem, here is my very specific solution.

If you have the wordpress plugin Post Types Order installed it will override your order query, i uninstalled it and everything magically worked!

Answer (score 0):

If you are having trouble with data getting sort by dates, you can add `'meta_type' => 'DATE'` to set the meta type.

Also solves the issue if you are not using a `meta_query` but just want to sort the data.

So it will be:

```
'meta_key'  => 'datum_dienst',
'orderby'   => 'meta_value',
'order'     => 'ASC',
'meta_type' => 'DATE'
```

More info: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/

> Use ‘meta_value_num‘ instead for numeric values. You may also specify
> ‘meta_type‘ if you want to cast the meta value as a specific type.
> Possible values are ‘NUMERIC’, ‘BINARY’, ‘CHAR’, ‘DATE’, ‘DATETIME’,
> ‘DECIMAL’, ‘SIGNED’, ‘TIME’, ‘UNSIGNED’, same as in ‘$meta_query‘.